# Is there a way to run a Wildfly bootable jar with external configurations?

Tags: wildfly, thorntail, wildfly-maven-plugin

I am currently evaluating if Wildfly bootable jar is a valid candidate to migrate from Thorntail. I am having trouble finding a way to externalize application properties.

Is there a way to have external properties such as HTTP ports, JDBC drivers and so on in an external file (e.g. application.yml) and run the bootable jar pointing to this file and integrating such properties?

For example in Thorntail it is done by passing a "-s" flag followed by the path to the config file we want to integrate:

**‘java -jar application.jar -s application_config.yml’**

How is this done in Wildfly?

Thanks!

Comment: The bootable JAR accepts some arguments: https://docs.wildfly.org/23/Bootable_Guide.html#wildfly-bootable-jar-arguments Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be anything for pointing towards an external `standalone.xml`, but you should be able to use `--cli-script` to execute a WildFly management script.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the server during packaging with an extra content, see https://docs.wildfly.org/bootablejar/#wildfly_jar_configuring_build